# Create a Table with name Based on Current Date on Azure Databricks (preferably SQL, but could do Python)

Tags: dynamic, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

I need to create a table using the current date in Azure Databricks.  Specifically I need the table name to look like this:

workbench.example_2003-11-5 (if the table were created today)

workbench.example_2003-11-6 (if the table were created tomorrow)

I tried the following:

```
SET p.myVar = CURRENT_DATE();

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE workbench.example_${p.myVar} AS

SELECT
"1"
;

SELECT *
FROM workbench.example_${p.myVar}
;
```

This turns the following error:

```
Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: could not resolve `prd.workbench.example_CURRENT_DATE` to a table-valued function; line 2 pos 5;
'Project [*]
+- 'UnresolvedTableValuedFunction [prd, workbench, example_CURRENT_DATE]
```

Declaring the parameter in a separate cell create a table named:

workbench.example_current_date()

Is there a way to pass a date into a table creation command Databricks SQL?  If there is no way to do this using Databricks SQL can you do it in Databricks Python?

Comment: @DileeprajnarayanThumula Yes.  Question editted.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below one if you are using Azure Databricks -

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

date = spark.sql("""select current_date() as cur_date""").first()["cur_date"]
dt = str(date).replace("-","_")

spark.sql("create table default.`{}` (id int)".format(dt))
```

Comment: Error in SQL statement: ParseException: 
[PARSE_SYNTAX_ERROR] Syntax error at or near '*'(line 1, pos 34)

== SQL ==
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
----------------------------------^^^

date = spark.sql("""select current_date() as cur_date""").first()["cur_date"]
dt = str(date).replace("-","_")

spark.sql("create table default.`{}` (id int)".format(dt))

Comment: The code above returns the following error.

Comment: You should run the code by selecting Python notebook